# What are the differences between slices and partitions of RDDs?

Tags: python, apache-spark

I am using Spark's Python API and running Spark 0.8.

I am storing a large RDD of floating point vectors and I need to perform calculations of one vector against the entire set.

Is there any difference between slices and partitions in an RDD?

When I create the RDD, I pass it 100 as a parameter which causes it to store the RDD as 100 slices and create 100 tasks when performing the calculations.  I want to know if partitioning the data would improve performance beyond the slicing by enabling the system to process the data more efficiently (i.e. is there a difference between performing operations over a partition versus over just operating over every element in the sliced RDD).

For example, is there any significant difference between these two pieces of code?

```
rdd = sc.textFile(demo.txt, 100)
```

vs

```
rdd = sc.textFile(demo.txt)
rdd.partitionBy(100)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23436640/what-is-the-different-between-an-rdd-partition-and-a-slice-in-apache-spark

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I believe `slices` and `partitions` are the same thing in Apache Spark.

However, there is a subtle but potentially significant difference between the two pieces of code you posted.

This code will *attempt* to load `demo.txt` directly into 100 partitions using 100 concurrent tasks:

```
rdd = sc.textFile('demo.txt', 100)
```

For uncompressed text, it will work as expected. But if instead of `demo.txt` you had a `demo.gz`, you will end up with an RDD with only 1 partition. Reads against gzipped files cannot be parallelized.

On the other hand, the following code will first open `demo.txt` into an RDD with the default number of partitions, *then* it will explicitly repartition the data into 100 partitions that are roughly equal in size.

```
rdd = sc.textFile('demo.txt')
rdd = rdd.repartition(100)
```

So in this case, even with a `demo.gz` you will end up with an RDD with 100 partitions.

As a side note, I replaced your `partitionBy()` with `repartition()` since that's what I believe you were looking for. `partitionBy()` requires the RDD to be an RDD of tuples. Since `repartition()` is not available in Spark 0.8.0, you should instead be able to use `coalesce(100, shuffle=True)`.

Spark can run 1 concurrent task for every partition of an RDD, up to the number of cores in your cluster. So if you have a cluster with 50 cores, you want your RDDs to at least have 50 partitions (and probably [2-3x times that](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/tuning.html#level-of-parallelism)).

As of Spark 1.1.0, you can check how many partitions an RDD has as follows:

```
rdd.getNumPartitions()  # Python API
rdd.partitions.size     // Scala API
```

Before 1.1.0, the way to do this with the Python API was `rdd._jrdd.splits().size()`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do partition as follows:

```
import org.apache.spark.Partitioner

val p = new Partitioner() {
  def numPartitions = 2
  def getPartition(key: Any) = key.asInstanceOf[Int]
}
recordRDD.partitionBy(p)
```